# hide specific div from iframe jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, iframe, phonegap

i'm creating webview application using phonegap
i'm using iframe method to show my website inside application
i need to show popup message for mobile browser users to download application
so i create simple div to show in mobile screen only due to it's size
how can i prevent this div from shown in my iframe application
i'm trying many tutorials and asks but not working for me 
this is my iframe page

```
<body>
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="http://www.medicamall.com"></iframe>
</body>
```

this is full code of my project

```js
$(window).load(function() {
 $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
});
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 
 function onDeviceReady() {
  setTimeout(function () {
   navigator.splashscreen.hide();
  }, 50);
 }

// offline event
function checkConnection() {
           var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
           var states = {};
           states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
           states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
           states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
           states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
           states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
           states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
           states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';
          
           return networkState;
          
       }
 function onDeviceReady() {
  var networkState = checkConnection();
  /* load local files if there is not network connection */
   if (networkState == Connection.NONE) {
     $('.openapp').children('a').attr("href","offline.html"); 
   } 
 }
```

```css
body {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;                /* prevent callout to copy image, etc when tap to hold */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;             /* prevent webkit from resizing text to fit */
    -webkit-user-select: none;                  /* prevent copy paste, to allow, change 'none' to 'text' */
    width:100%;
}
html {
 height:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 height:100%;
}
#iframe {
 border:none;
 width:100%; 
 height:100%;
}
.loader {
 position: fixed;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 9999;
 background: url('../img/Preloader.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <!-- This is a wide open CSP declaration. To lock this down for production, see below. -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-

 <title>Medica Mall</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
 <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="loader"></div>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="http://www.medicamall.com"></iframe>
    
 <script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
  
 </script>
 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: For the communication bitween parent and child you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage .

Answer (score 0):

To hide a div which is in the iframe, you can use the following:

```
$("#iframe").contents().find("#your_div_id").hide();
```

You need to use `.contents()` to get access to iframe's inner elements, and then you can use usual jQuery selectors to do whatever you want with it.

Comment: that works only, if the parent and child is in the same domain. in the case of the webapp it should work.

Comment: thanks @31piy for your help  exactly Mic it's work only in the same domain , in my case it's not working

Comment: @MohamedMehanny : then you can use the postMesaage functions but you to have access to the code of the child page.

Answer (score 0):

To communicate between parent and child frames, use [postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) method. This also has the ability to work cross-domain (see [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) for more information on that) as long as you have access to both websites.

Comment: i don't know how to work with this function, i'm trying but i can't understand how to work with postMessage to hide div

Comment: Basically in your iframe website, you add a listener for postMessage() and in your parent website you send a message. When the iframe website gets a message, you can execute your function to hide the div for example. The examples in this link actually are very good for your case.

Comment: i get this error in debug of iframe page " uncaught referenceerror receiveMessage is not defined "

Comment: Can you please share your Code?

Comment: i added it in the question

Comment: receiveMessage is the function you call when a message is received. You did not declare a function called "receiveMessage". But anyway, the message listener should be placed in the website that is embedded in the iFrame and not in the parent website.